# Best way to convert and array of objects into a simplistic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I have an array of objects. Basically, each object has 2 keys named `id` and `value`. Now I have to convert this array into an another array but with respect to ids.

Eg

```
const arr1 = [{
    "month": "April",
    "values": [{
       "id": "rice",
       "value": 10
    },
    {
       "id": "wheat",
       "value": 20
    },
    {
       "id": "corn",
       "value": 30
    }]
},{
    "month": "May",
    "values": [{
       "id": "rice",
       "value": 40
    },
    {
       "id": "wheat",
       "value": 50
    },
    {
       "id": "corn",
       "value": 60
    }]
},{
    "month": "June",
    "values": [{
       "id": "rice",
       "value": 70
    },
    {
       "id": "wheat",
       "value": 80
    },
    {
       "id": "corn",
       "value": 90
    }]
}]
```

I want to take out values and make it something like

```
const arr2 = [{
   id: "rice",
   values: [10,40,70],
},{
   id: "wheat",
   values: [20,50,80],
},{
   id: "corn",
   values: [30,60,90],
}]
```

arranged in order of dates.

What I have tried

```
const ids = arr1[0].values.map(value => value.id);
const arr2 = ids.map(id => {
    return {
        id,
        values:[]
    }
}
```

I am unable to think of how to fill the values. The most obvious way will require 3 loops which should not be a good idea.

What should i do?

Comment: Looking at your data might give you clues. Will every month have data for all crops in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```js
const extractValues = months => 
  Object .entries (months 
    .flatMap (({values}) => values)
    .reduce ((a, {id, value}) => ({...a, [id]: [...(a [id] || []), value]}), {})
  ) .map (([id, values]) => ({id, values}))

const months = [{month: "April", values: [{id: "rice", value: 10}, {id: "wheat", value: 20}, {id: "corn", value: 30}]}, {month: "May", values: [{id: "rice", value: 40}, {id: "wheat", value: 50}, {id: "corn", value: 60}]}, {month: "June", values: [{id: "rice", value: 70}, {id: "wheat", value: 80}, {id: "corn", value: 90}]}]

console .log (extractValues (months))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by flat-mapping the original array to combine all the `value` nodes in a single array, so it will contain `rice/10`, `wheat/20`, `corn/30`, `rice/40`, ..., `corn/90`, in objects like your original: `{id: 'rice', value: 10}`.

Then with `reduce`, we combine those into

```js
{
  rice: [10, 40, 70],
  wheat: [20, 50, 80],
  corn: [30, 60, 90]
}
```

We use `Object.entries` to extract that into

```js
[
  ['rice', [10, 40, 70]],
  ['wheat', [20, 50, 80]],
  ['corn', [30, 60, 90]]
]
```

and then we `map` over them, converting this into your expected output structure.

We retain the order of the inputs, and don't try to resort by your month.  That would not be much more work, but it's a reasonable guess that the data will already be sorted that way.

### Update

I was curious about the possibility that the data is less consistent, and thought I'd rewrite in a way that handled that.  In this version, we also have one month that has `soybean` records, and `June` is in the array before `May`.  So we need to sort on the months, and capture all the ids we might need in any of them.  It looks like this:

```js
const byMonth = ((months) => (a, b) => 
  (months .indexOf (a .month) || 13) - (months .indexOf (b .month) || 13) 
)(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'])

const extract = (
  xs,
  months = [... xs] .sort (byMonth),
  ids = [... new Set (months .flatMap (({values}) => values .map (({id}) => id)))]
) => ids .map ((id) => ({
  id,
  values: months .map (m => (m .values .find (v => v.id == id) || {value: null}) .value)
}))

const months = [{month: "April", values: [{id: "rice", value: 10}, {id: "wheat", value: 20}, {id: "corn", value: 30}]}, {month: "June", values: [{id: "rice", value: 40}, {id: "wheat", value: 50}, {id: "corn", value: 60}]}, {month: "May", values: [{id: "rice", value: 70}, {id: "wheat", value: 80}, {id: "soybeans", value: 42}, {id: "corn", value: 90}]}]

console .log (extract (months))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that the output now has some `nulls` to note that there were no `soybean` records in April or June, only in May:

```js
  {
    id: "soybeans",
    values: [null, 42, null]
  }
```

This sort of working around inconsistent data is a large part of my job, and of many developers I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr2 = arr1.flatMap(x => x.values);
arr2.map(x => ({ 
    id: x.id, 
    value: arr2
        .filter(y => y.id === x.id)
        .map(y => y.value) 
}));
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: In this case you will not get the unique records by the way. If it's needed, we can initially extract the ids list.

Comment: This doesn't work, it repeats the accumated objects for every original element.

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of values using `Array.flatMap()`, and then reduce to a Map, and transform to an array of object by converting the Map using `Array.from()`:

```js
const fn = months => 
  Array.from(months 
    .flatMap(({ values }) => values)
    .reduce(
      (acc, o) => acc.set(o.id, [...(acc.get(o.id) ?? []), o.value]),
      new Map()
    ),
    ([id, values]) => ({ id, values })
  )

const months = [{month: "April", values: [{id: "rice", value: 10}, {id: "wheat", value: 20}, {id: "corn", value: 30}]}, {month: "May", values: [{id: "rice", value: 40}, {id: "wheat", value: 50}, {id: "corn", value: 60}]}, {month: "June", values: [{id: "rice", value: 70}, {id: "wheat", value: 80}, {id: "corn", value: 90}]}]

console .log (fn (months))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really just a 'group by' operation with a nested array. As such, you can handle it in a single `reduce()` call, with a nested loop over each `values` array.

```js
const arr1 = [ { month: 'April', values: [ { id: 'rice', value: 10, }, { id: 'wheat', value: 20, }, { id: 'corn', value: 30, }, ], }, { month: 'May', values: [ { id: 'rice', value: 40, }, { id: 'wheat', value: 50, }, { id: 'corn', value: 60, }, ], }, { month: 'June', values: [ { id: 'rice', value: 70, }, { id: 'wheat', value: 80, }, { id: 'corn', value: 90, }, ], }, ];

const result = Object.values(
  arr1.reduce((a, { values }) => {
    for (const { id, value } of values) {
      (a[id] ??= { id, values: [] }).values.push(value);
    }

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or using nested `reduce()` calls passing a single `Map` instance to both.

```js
const arr1 = [ { month: 'April', values: [ { id: 'rice', value: 10, }, { id: 'wheat', value: 20, }, { id: 'corn', value: 30, }, ], }, { month: 'May', values: [ { id: 'rice', value: 40, }, { id: 'wheat', value: 50, }, { id: 'corn', value: 60, }, ], }, { month: 'June', values: [ { id: 'rice', value: 70, }, { id: 'wheat', value: 80, }, { id: 'corn', value: 90, }, ], }, ];

const result = Array.from(
  arr1.reduce(
    (a, { values }) => 
      values.reduce((b, { id, value }) => b.set(id, [...(b.get(id) ?? []), value])
        , a)
    , new Map()
  ),
  (e) => Object.fromEntries([e])
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```